# What kind and how many Certificates are needed?

Tags: certificate, asp.net, iis

I have 3 ASP.NET-Web.Api Applications communicating together over https:

- Master on Server1
- Slave1 on Server1
- Slave2 on Server2 (Slave2 is basicly an other instance of Slave1 installed on another server)

Master communicates with Slave1 and Slave2.

Slave1 and Slave2 communicates with Master.

I have already certificates for SSL.

However I want to ensure that only Slave1 and Slave2 can talk to Master and vice versa. What kind of Certificates I need to ensure this trust?

Am I right that with the assumption that I need 3 Certificates for each App?

Last but not least: Does IIS handle the trusts or do I need to implement something in my code?

Comment: @TildalWave apologies, t's not a client-server relationship so maybe master-slave is not the best name to use ist. they 2 different appls (Master/Slave) that need to exchange some information.

Comment: Yes exactly like that :)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [Client Certificate Authentication](http://www.piotrwalat.net/client-certificate-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-store-apps/), this uses SSL to authenticate the Slaves to the Master and vice-versa. I know it can be done between browsers and webservers, but I'm not sure how you would be able to do it between servers. But this more a matter for [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) than Security.SE, so I would ask those guys.

Another option would be to use a VPN between your servers instead of using SSL authentication over the internet.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. Is it possible to migrate it to migrate it to Serverfault, if not I will copy/paste the question over there.

Answer (score 0):

If the communication is already encrypted, you could utilize [IP Address and Domain Restrictions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831785.aspx) module in IIS 7.x

Simply install the feature from Server Manager if it's not already present.

To add IP restrictions to a web site:

1. Choose the website or application in IIS manager.
2. Double-click the "IP and Domain Restrictions" feature
3. Choose "Edit feature settings" and set the default mode to Deny
4. Add the appropriate IP addresses to the site and choose to "Allow" those

Voila. Only requests from allowed IP addresses will now be served, all others will receive an HTTP 403 "Forbidden"

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that feature because there are other Services on master/slave that need to be "public"

Comment: Just apply it to the application or vDir that you want to restrict access to, everything else will still be accessible